# Present Continuous with going to

Tags: future-tense, infinitive-vs-gerund

What is the difference between these?

1. I am going to run.
2. I am going running.

Do those mean the same thing as each other?  Do they mean the same thing as any or all of these next ones?

3. I am going to go run.
4. I am going to go running.
5. I will go run.
6. I will go running.
7. I will be going running.

I am teaching my student the present continuous construction with *be going to* as an alternative to *will* for expressing future events, and he asked me the difference between the first two sentences.

Comment: 'Be going to' is one of the ways English English shows a future occurrence; it is a semi-modal construction rather than a tense. See FumbleFinger's answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42961/is-am-going-a-verb-phrase/42987#42987). //  'Go shopping / running / hiking / fishing / singing....' is what CoBuild call a 'phase structure', where the two verbs essentially describe a single two-component action. See the duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the -ing and to-infinitive "verbs" that follow catenative verbs always take the grammatical function of "noun"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184320/do-the-ing-and-to-infinitive-verbs-that-follow-catenative-verbs-always-take-t) (I like running, I started ..., I'm going shopping ...)

Comment: Pragmatically, someone announcing that they were going to leave the house (etc) and go for a run would say either "I'm going [out] for a run" or "I'm going running." "I am going to run" would only be used after say "How are you going to get to your aunt's [by 2 pm]?" / "You must not take part in the Marathon so soon after your operation!" / "Did you decide whether to enter for the 200m? ... "I _am_ going to run" (stressed reply).

Comment: This has been migrated? Phase-structure catenatives and semi-modal constructions are unsuitable on ELU? They weren't the first time round.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There was a request for migration,  so I migrated it. If this was wrong, we can take it back.

Comment: @tchrist As usual, my 'beef' is an attempt to set out and encourage what I consider to be correct assessment / practice rather than to correct a single perceived anomaly. Hence the (really-should-be-on-Meta-if-I'm-that-keen-on-sticking-to-all-the-rules) comments.

Answer (score 0):

"I am going to run" To be going (+to infinitive) expresses a planned future action. This expresses the idea that you are about to start running.(It is similar to, but not exactly the same as, "I will run.")

"I am going running" -> running is a gerund and the complement of "to go". This expresses the idea that you are about to leave in order to run.